# Standard way of generating/ writing XML files

Tags: python, xml

For a project, I need to generate XML files which adhere to a specific format. I was wondering, what is the standard way of doing this?

For my part I am using `lxml` and then writing the XML files. For this, I wrote a small script that takes in XML data as input and then generates the files.

Is this way of doing it 'OK'? Cause I am new to all this and I have seen many people use TeX and then convert it to XML.

Or is there a better of way doing it altogether?

EDIT: Note that I have to allow the end user to generate these files without any effort required from them.

Comment: "allow the end user to generate these files without any effort required from them."  Makes no sense.  What's "Effort"?  XML is a huge pain to work with, how can any human being work with XML manually?

Answer (score 1):

For python 3: http://diveintopython3.org/xml.html#xml-parse